# Make <li> tags editable

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I need something like html `<ul>` list.

It should contains bullets and something like textarea. [image]

```css
textarea{
  border : none;
}
.custom-txt-area{border-bottom : 1px dashed red;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <textarea class="custom-txt-area" rows="1"></textarea>
  </li>
  <li>
    <textarea class="custom-txt-area" rows="1"></textarea>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is very sample example. Problem here - I can't make `textarea` extend it height to the bottom if it contans more than 1 row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `contentEditable`:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehucxw14/)

```html
<ul>
      <li contenteditable="true">Edit ME!</li>
      <li contenteditable="true">Edit ME!</li>
      <li contenteditable="true">Edit ME!</li>
      <li contenteditable="true">Edit ME!</li>
      <li contenteditable="true">Edit ME!</li>
      <li contenteditable="true">Edit ME!</li>
    </ul>
```